# G++ 4.4 "uninitialized" variables

Tags: c++, g++, initialization

I am using g++ on Ubuntu 10.10(64-bit) if the OS is at all relevant for the matter.
I saw something strange so i decided to check and for some reason this code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

always prints 0. Obviously g++ does auto initialization of uninitialized variables to their corresponding null-value. The thing is I want to turn that feature off, or at least make g++ show warning about using uninitialized variables, since this way my code won't work well when compiled on VS for instance. Besides I'm pretty sure the C++ standard states that a variable which isn't implicitly initialized with some value has an undefined value amongst all it's possible values, which should in fact be different with every execution of the program, since different parts of the operating memory are used every time it's executed.

Explicit question:  Is there a way to make g++ show warnings for uninitialized variables?

Comment: -Wall http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_30.html

Comment: closed as not a real question.

Comment: What "undefined" means is that the Standard doesn't say what will happen.  It doesn't rule out the possibility that all available implementations will do the exact same thing under all circumstances.  Specifically, if you could count on different values, that would be some sort of definition of the behavior.

Comment: @Johannes:  The question of how to make g++ warn of uninitialized variables is a legitimate, if minor, one.  It may be a duplicate, but it's a real question.

Comment: @David I read the post closely and I could not find such a question. All I found is it stating wrong conclusions like "Obviously g++ does auto initialization" or state wishes "I want to turn that feature off, or at least make g++ show warning about using uninitialized variables". @kunev if you clarify your question, with a clear '?' sign somewhere that defines the question, I would be glad to help.

Comment: @Johannes, point taken. Is there a way to make g++ show warnings for uninitialized variables?

Comment: @kunev: you should probably edit your question, making it clearer

Comment: At least basic types(int,double,float,char,and corresponding pointers) all receive 0/NULL/'\0' as a default value.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: I think it was easy to understand that the question was "Is there a way to make g++ show warnings for uninitialized variables?", although it wasn't that explicit. Did it deserve to be closed anyway according to the community _rules_?

Comment: @kunev: if I compile your snippet with GCC 4.5.2 and run it, it prints some random values (`-1217257484` at the first run, `-1217638412` at the second one...). Anyway even if your distribution's GCC 4.4 initialized variables to 0 that would be meaningless, since it's not standard, and just by changing compiler distributor, version or vendor you could get different values since the standard explicitly says uninitialized variables don't need to be 0.

Comment: @peoro It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, for me. However, after reviewing by decisions, I see it probably was a bit too premature to draw a close-vote. I would be glad to take it back.

Comment: I just edited the question to make the actual question stand out, to avoid future confusion.  Kunev, if you would, in future questions, make it more clear exactly what you are asking, that might help you get better answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC does not initialize uninitialized variables to 0. It's just a case that `a` is `0`.

If what you want to do is to receive warnings when you use uninitialized variables you could use GCC option `-Wuninitialized` (also included by `-Wall`).

However it can't statically spot any possible usage of uninitialized variables: you'll need some run time tools to spot that, and there's `valgrind` for this.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try to use a tool like [cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page#Checks). In general, in well written C++ there is rarely a reason to declare a variable without initializing it.